# Clearing data from previous instances in R

Tags: r

I have a program that examines data from CSV files - these files typically have 5 groups of varying observation length. When I run data that has less than 5 groups (say 4 groups), the remaining group's data will still be present in the calculations. A typical data set will look like this, call it "A":

```
    Group 1      Group 2      Group 3     Group 4      Group 5
    2548.64      2879.32      2964.61     2567.65      2548.69
    2635.78      2954.37      3215.49     2867.98      2897.65
    2534.61      2497.64      3015.87     2345.98      2478.66
    2897.91      3159.67      2467.99     2599.08      2499.37
    3079.97      2664.82      2311.64     2849.78      2888.54
                              2864.55     2999.15      2657.81
                                          2499.88      2754.65
                                          3097.45      2665.39
```

An atypical data set will look like, call it "B":

```
    Group 1      Group 2      Group 3     Group 4 
    2651.32      2941.3       2848.97     2599.11
    2864.22      2489.67      2957.34     2987.46
    2687.22      2999.25      3102.87
    2956.34      2677.1       2877.61
    2488.77
```

If I run any sort of operation on B, the data from A's Group 5 will fill in the "missing" data from B. What is the best way to clear the data from A, before I run B?

Comment: Do you use `attach` in your analysis?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what objects contain the Group 1-5 data, so I will just assume that after you read in the "A" csv file, you create a separate object for each group, called `g1`, `g2`, `g3`, `g4`, `g5`.  Then, when you read in a the "B" csv file, you also create a separate object for each group, recycling the names you used in "A", `g1`, `g2`, `g3`, `g4`.  In this case, you could clear the information from "A" using the `rm()` function before reading in the data from "B".

```
rm(g1, g2, g3, g4, g5)
```

Comment: Technically correct, but attaching dataframes is not a good idea. It will save OP a lot of headaches in the future to unlearn this instead of fixing the first problems associated with it.

Comment: The OP does not say whether "A" and "B" are data frames and does not say if "A" and "B" are attached.  My answer does not assume either.

Comment: A and B are both Data Frames. The rm() function did do the trick for me.